# Cannot delete Custom Entities and it's not about relations

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I created a fresh new entity which has no additional fields or relations to anything and also without any records.
Just after i created the entity and when i try to delete it, it gives me the following error:

```
An error has occurred.
```

And in the log file which can be downloaded from the error dialog:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: collection
```

And when enabled tracing the error was:

```
Process: w3wp |Organization:0220cef0-4f09-e711-80d8-000c2950db72 |Thread:  244 |Category: Platform.Metadata |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 17d8623e-7539-48af-9652-b8550acfb76f | EntityService.Delete  ilOffset = 0x1A8
>EntityService.Update caught exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: collection
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CascadeEngine.LogRecordSetCount(Int32 count, IEnumerable`1 entityIds, Int32 parentEntityObjectTypeCode, String perfCounterName)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CascadeEngine.CascadeDeleteDB(IEnumerable`1 parentEntityIds, Int32 parentEntityObjectTypeCode, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CascadeEngine.Delete(IEnumerable`1 entityIds, Int32 entityObjectTypeCode, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.CascadeEngine.DeleteAll(Int32 entityObjectTypeCode, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.EntityService.Delete(Guid entityId, MetadataHelper metadataHelper, Boolean suppressSecurityCacheFlush, ExecutionContext context)
```

Well i don't know whats wrong. Please let me know if you know anything. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an error in the Dynamics CRM product itself. Tried to publish all customizations and then delete the entity?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is if there are any dependencies, which you can do by selecting the entity in a solution and clicking Show Dependencies:

[image]

Comment: I checked all dependencies by "Show Dependencies" button, and all dependencies is some sort of systematic, like business_unit relation, System Jobs, Bulk Delete and ... also its edit forms is disabled and can't be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I did noticed something that this error only happens when Persian language pack is installed, but when its just CRM with no language packs everything is fine.
So at least i know what to do now and it's not something useful to be discussed further here.
Thanks.